# scala pass T type to Java constructor

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I am using Jackson read Yaml in scala 2.11/2.12 `val mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())`, I think the Java constructor I am calling is

```
public <T> T readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)
```

this code works

```
def load(): SomeClass {
  mapper.readValue[SomeClass](configStr, classOf[SomeClass])
}
```

But I want to change this class to `T`

```
mapper.readValue[T](configStr, classOf[T])
```

error `class type required but T found`

I searched some  and changed it to

```
def load[T: ClassTag](): T = {
  mapper.readValue[T](configStr, classTag[T].runtimeClass)
}
```

But it says no construct methods are matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `classTag[T].runtimeClass` is a `Class[?]`, you have to use `.asInstanceOf` (safe in this usage):

```scala
mapper.readValue[T](configStr, classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
```

*Note that if you were using the Jackson Scala module, such methods are already provided to you in order to avoid the boilerplate*